# Copying a SkipList / Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, skip-lists

In the programming assignment, I need to clone a linked list (its a copy constructor so not returning anything but cloning). The old linked list will be going through some removing and adding elements but the new cloned linked list should remain untouched. How do I do that? When I remove and add new nodes to the old list, it also does the same for the new linked list. How can I avoid this?

```
  this->head = other.head;
  this->head->val = other.head->val;

  SNode *curr = other.head->next;
  SNode *newCurr = nullptr;
  while (curr != nullptr) {
    newCurr = curr;
    curr = curr->next;
  }
}
```

I have tried the above code, but when I modify the old list, ie, adding and removing nodes, it also adds and removes nodes from the new list. What can I do to avoid the modifications happening on the new list?

Comment: Your code doesn't add anything to `this->head->next[i]`, if that's what you want.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I apologize for that, that [i] is for the skip list. I modified my code to work for a linked list so it is easier to understand.

Comment: You are still not copying anything to the `this` object, if that's your purpose. You just iterate over the list from the second node to the last. The assignment `newCurr = curr` is effectively useless and doesn't do anything.

Comment: If you are going to clone a list, then surely you need to allocate some new nodes for the new list. Your code does not do that, so it cannot be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not creating new nodes, so this cannot work. A cloned list should consist of new nodes, so the `SNode` constructor should be called.

For instance:

```
this->head = other.head;
```

This will just make the new list point to the same list: now you have two `head` pointers pointing to the same head node. And then, by consequence, the following assignment doesn't do anything useful, as it really is assigning a member's own value to itself:

```
this->head->val = other.head->val;
```

The loop isn't doing anything useful either, as it is not assigning anything to any member that belongs to the new structure. It only assigns to variables, walking through the original list with two variables, where `newCurr` follows one step behind `curr`.

Here is a correction of your snippet:

```
  // Deal with boundary case: empty list
  this->head = NULL;
  if (other.head == NULL) return; // Nothing more to do.
  
  // Clone the head node
  this->head = new SNode(other.head->val);

  SNode *curr = other.head->next;
  SNode *tail = this->head; // tail is a more descriptive name
  while (curr != nullptr) {
    tail->next = new SNode(curr->val); // Clone current node and append it
    tail = tail->next; // This new node is now the tail
    curr = curr->next;
  }
```

This assumes you have an `SNode` constructor that takes a single argument for the node's value.